# Add "starting at" if products have options in Opencart category page

Tags: php, themes, opencart

I need to show in the category page of opencart

Starting at € xx.xx if this product have options.

Something like this:

```
if (have options) {
    print starting at $price
} else {
    print $price }
```

category.tpl contains:

```
<p class="price">
<?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
<?php echo $product['price']; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
<span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

I need to insert another controller that, if we have options show "starting at €..." instead the price.

Thank you all,
Davide

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hello @Szenis, i'm sorry, i'm Italian and maybe i have problems with english!!

I need to insert in my opencart template "category.php" file a code that allow to see (if the product has options) "price starts at €..." else, if the product doesn't have options, show the price.

Example:
Tshirt (M = 12€, L = 14€, XL = 16€ )
in category page i need to show
Tshirt:
starting at 12 € (the lowest options price)

Comment: Do you already have a variable with the option inside it?

Comment: No @Szenis, it is my problem. I don't know what i've to put inside the variable, i've done that in single product page, but in category it's different.

Comment: Are you using a database? if so you need to add a field called options or something like that, then you could read from that database if there is a option. I can try to help and explain you but could you post some of your code?

Comment: Thank you @Szenis, i've added the code of the category.tpl file in the post. I have installed the original opencart database.

Comment: so then u can add a field called option and in your code do something like if($product['option'] == 'show') { // your code here }    please say if i understood you wrong

Comment: Prompt how to modify that it considered the minimum price (price without options or the price of the first option chosen) and the second price (price + the most expensive option).

Comment: Please clarify with a code example...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29181832/7475810 It works here, but analyzes only one option. For example in the product several options: the first option: 200 euros, the second option: 300 euros, a third option: 400 euros. And the price of goods is 150 euros. It is necessary that the price displayed "150 - 400 euro"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed something similar for a client in Opencart (v1.5.5.1). The following code checks to see if there is an option **with a price increase** and if so puts 'From price' on the category page:

Add the following function to ***\catalog\model\catalog\product.php***

```
public function hasOptionPriceIncrease($product_id) {
  $option_data = $this->getProductOptions($product_id);
  if (is_array($option_data)) {
    foreach ($option_data as $option) {
      if (is_array($option['option_value'])) {
        foreach ($option['option_value'] as $value) {
          if ($value['price'] > 1) {
            return true;
          }
        }  
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

**in opencart > 2.0** use `product_option_value` instead of `option_value`:

```
public function hasOptionPriceIncrease($product_id) {
  $option_data = $this->getProductOptions($product_id);
    if (is_array($product_option_value)) {
      foreach ($product_option_value as $option) {
      if (is_array($option['product_option_value'])) {
        foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $value) {
          if ($value['price'] > 1) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }    
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then add the following line to the `$this->data['products'][]` array in the category controller: \controller\product\category.php

```
      'has_option_price_increase' =>$this->model_catalog_product->hasOptionPriceIncrease($result['product_id'])
```

This is at around line 250 on mine but yours maybe a bit different it goes in here:

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
  'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
  'thumb'       => $image,
  'name'        => $result['name'],
  'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
  'price'       => $price,
  'special'     => $special,
  'tax'         => $tax,
  'rating'      => $result['rating'],
  'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
  'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url),
  'has_option_price_increase' =>$this->model_catalog_product->hasOptionPriceIncrease($result['product_id'])
);
```

Don't forget to add the comma at the end of the preceding line.

Then you can add something similar to the following in the view: ***\catalog\view\theme\duvalay\template\product\category.tpl***

```
<p class="price">
 <?php if ($product['has_option_price_increase']) { echo 'From'; } ?>
```

Comment: oh wow, thank you @jx12345 !
That's the solution, but i've opencart 2.0.1.1 and i **get a error**: `Undefined variable: product_option in
htdocs/shop/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 516`.

I think the variable $product_option doesn't exist anymore in new wordpress.

Please, tell me if you have any idea. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @DavideTubia, that's a bit weird I don't think there is any reference to a variable $product_option in my code - could that be related to something else perhaps? Also you mention wordpress are you using that in conjunction with opencart or was that just a typo?

Comment: it's ok now, as i've already told, variable `product_option` is changed in `product_option_value`. Now it's working. Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: oh i see, excellent, if it works maybe you could accept it as the correct answer and maybe give it an upvote :)

Comment: checked as correct answer, but i cannot upvote, i need "15 reputation"

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by jx12345 is very useful, however, I spent the better part of the afternoon trying to figure out why it wasn't working on OC v2.0.3.1 and figured out that the solution was simply a matter of changing the original array check variable. The original variable he has

```
$option_data
```

needs to be changed to

```
$product_option_value
```

So the final code to add to the model file looks something like this:

```
public function hasOptionPriceIncrease($product_id) {
  $product_option_value = $this->getProductOptions($product_id);
    if (is_array($product_option_value)) {
     foreach ($product_option_value as $option) {
      if (is_array($option['product_option_value'])) {
       foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $value) {
         if ($value['price'] > 1) {
           return true;
         }
       }
     }
   }    
 }
return false;
}
```

At least this is what was necessary to get the code working for me.

Thanks for the contribution jx12345!